# How to evaluate and group together matched elements

Tags: jquery

If my HTML looks something like:

```
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>green</h1></div>
<div><h1>pink</h1></div>
```

What's the best approach in jQuery to evaluate how many h1 matches there are, and, if the match count is > 1 for a particular h1, put its div inside a container div:

```
<div class="matches">
    <div><h1>red</h1></div>
    <div><h1>red</h1></div>
    <div><h1>red</h1></div>
    <div><h1>red</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="matches">
    <div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
    <div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
    <div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
</div>
<div><h1>green</h1></div>
<div><h1>pink</h1></div>
```

I'm getting hung up with an each() function that returns every h1 to me, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach (jQuery newb trying to break into new territory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $containers = $('div'),
    $headings = $containers.find('> h1'),
    targetContainer = 'body',
    matches = {};

/*
 * First we traverse through the headings
 * pushing exact matches to a 'matches' object
 */
$headings.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();

    if (typeof matches[text] === 'undefined') {
        matches[text] = [];
    }

    matches[text].push($this.closest('div')[0]);
});

/*
 * Remove the initial, unsorted collection
 */
$containers.remove();

/*
 * Now let's see if we have duplicate
 * headings.
 */
for (group in matches) {
    if (matches[group].length > 1) {

        /*
         * Put them all in a '.matches' div
         * and append to our target container
         * e.g. body
         */
        $('<div class="matches"></div>').html(matches[group]).appendTo(targetContainer);

        /*
         * Delete the group
         * after use
         */
        delete matches[group];
    }
}

/*
 * This is optional:
 * I used two separate loops to
 * put unmatched headings after the
 * matched groups.
 *
 * You could use the if..else from
 * the previous loop.
 */

for (group in matches) {
    $(matches[group]).appendTo(targetContainer);
}
```

This code will work even with mixed, unordered collection, like

```
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>green</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>red</h1></div>
<div><h1>yellow</h1></div>
<div><h1>pink</h1></div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As I mentioned it is possible to keep matched and non-matched groups together — remove the second `for..in` loop and use the `if..else` as follows:

```
/* ...
 * Now let's see if we have duplicate
 * headings.
 */
for (group in matches) {
    if (matches[group].length > 1) {

        /*
         * Put them all in a '.matches' div
         * and append to our target container
         * e.g. body
         */
        $('<div class="matches"></div>').html(matches[group]).appendTo(targetContainer);
    } else {
        $(matches[group]).appendTo(targetContainer);
    }
}
```

However, due to the way JavaScript objects are stored in memory it is not possible to predict the order of enumeration.

Comment: +1 for perfect solution : here is [`working fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ufuKE/1) of above

Comment: Thanks Lapple! The commenting helped a ton as well. The fiddle was a nice assist, diEcho.

Comment: Thinking about this further, Lapple, is there any way to keep matches in original order? If it's pink, red, red, blue blue, green -- can we have those matches between the singles or by the nature of this solution the singles always fall below the matches?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('div').eq(0).before('<div class="matches">');

var  this_element= '';
var next_element = '';
var length = 0 ;
$('div').each(function(){

    this_element= $(this).find('h1').text();
    next_element = $(this).next('div').find('h1').text();


   if((this_element!= next_element) && (next_element!='') && (length>0)){

       $(this).after('</div><div class="matches">');
       length = 0 ;
   }
   if((!next_element) && (length>0)){
        $(this).after('</div>');
        length = 0 ;
   }
     length++;
});
```